# Uploading File in iMacros

Tags: imacros

I'm trying to upload a file to a website via iMacros. Normally this is pretty easy and you would use code like the following:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:example ATTR=NAME:uploaded_file CONTENT=file_path_goes_here
```

However, there is no `INPUT:FILE` tag on this page. So the code above does not work.

When you click the upload button on this web site, its just a link that does a postback and then magically a `File Upload` dialog box appears.

iMacros has no mechanism for writing to upload dialog boxes from what I know.

Any ideas on how to approach this or any experience uploading files via iMacros via non-traditional upload methods?

Thanks

Comment: This could be something with the site. iMacros can't upload on some sites. Drop it.